# "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required..." error after upload laravel 5 project to server

Tags: php, laravel

It is first time that I want to upload and share a Laravel 5 project into server.

I study many resources and topics on the web for solve this problem but I can not.

this is Structure of my folders and files on the server :

[image]

And this is my changes in **public_html/index.php** file :

```
require __DIR__.'/../tc/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../tc/bootstrap/app.php';
```

according other studied Topics I think that all thing is ok. but when opening main domain I was faced with the following errors:

```
Warning: require(/home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/../tc/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/index.php on line 22

Warning: require(/home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/../tc/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/../tc/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tc/domains/tc-iran.ir/public_html/index.php on line 22
```

what is Problem and solution?

Comment: Have you set the permissions and ownership of the uploaded files correctly?

Comment: `public_html` has 775 and `tc` that contains all laravel files has 755 permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Why by I solve this problem .

I just move `tc` (main laravel content project files) into `domains` Next another `public_html`folder that exists there .

This is New folders Structure on the server:

[image]